# Rails 4 : unknown attribute: shared_attachments_attributes for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

models/participant_attachment.rb

```
class ParticipantAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :participant
  has_many :shared_attachments
  validates_presence_of :attachment

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shared_attachments, reject_if: :all_blank,
           allow_destroy: true
end
```

model/shared_attachment.rb

```
class SharedAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :participant
  belongs_to :participant_attachment
end
```

shared_attachment.html.haml

```
    %ul
      - @participants.each do |participant|
        = hidden_field_tag 'participant_attachments[shared_attachments_attributes][][participant_attachment_id]', @attachment.id rescue nil
        %li
          %label= participant.full_name
          = check_box_tag "participant_attachments[shared_attachments_attributes][][participant_id]", participant.id, @shared_participants.include?(participant.id.to_s)
```

participant_attachments_controller.rb

```
  def create_shared_participants
    shared_participants = SharedAttachment.new(activity_params)
    shared_participants.save
  end

  def activity_params
    params.require(:participant_attachments).permit(
      :participant_id, :attachment, shared_attachments_attributes: [:participant_id, :participant_attachment_id]
    )
  end
```

I am trying to save multiple checkboxes' values using accespts_nested_attributes_for. but getting error like unknown attribute: shared_attachments_attributes.any solution ?

Here is the log :

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"efwsP0tQksCSQqwqoH2qJwANJ/OFChQviG+4Kz8SYgI=", "participant_attachments"=>{"shared_attachments_attributes"=>[{"participant_attachment_id"=>"14", "participant_id"=>"2"}, {"participant_attachment_id"=>"14", "participant_id"=>"4"}]}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: shared_attachments_attributes):
  app/controllers/participant/participant_attachments_controller.rb:34:in `create_shared_participants'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do have `participant_id` two times in your `activity_params`? Try changing your `activity_params` to `params.require(:participant_attachments).permit(:attachment, shared_attachments_attributes: [:participant_id, :participant_attachment_id])`

Comment: @pavan - participant_id is for another model and in shared_attachments_attributes: [:participant_id] is for another model. Means here i am giving permission to multiple model attributed. i tried your solution but same result..:(

Answer (score 0):

[**`fields_for`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

The problem is most likely a result of not correctly using `fields_for` helper in your `form_for` element.

Typically, when you set an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` argument in your `model`, you'll pass the relative data to your controller / model with `fields_for`, not setting them by hand as you have:

```
#app/controllers/participant_attachments_controller.rb
Class ParticipantAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @participants = ParticipantAttachment.all
      @participant_attachment = ParticipantAttachment.new

      @participants.each do
         @participant_attachment.shared_attachments.build
      end
   end
end

#app/views/participant_attachments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @participant_attachments do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :shared_attachments do |sa| %>
        <%= sa.text_field :participant_id %>
        <%= sa.text_field :participant_attachment_id
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will automatically give you 3 sets of "nested" model attributes, which you'll be able to send through to your model.

I'm not sure if this will resolve your problem directly, but I know it's what you *should* be doing to ensure you're able to get your application working correctly